# Making Nivo Slider Direction Navigation Arrow FADE In With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

Can't get this... trying to make the direction navigation arrows on [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) fade in rather then just *appear*. Here's the code that hide/shows the directional nab:

```
//Hide Direction nav
if(settings.directionNavHide){
    $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
    slider.hover(function(){
        $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).show();
    }, function(){
        $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
    });
}
```

I'd assume it's as easy as changing `.hide()` to `.fadeOut('fast')` and `.show()` to `.fadeIn('fast')`. However, after the first slide change, they go back to just *appearing*. (see that issue [here](http://www.bridgecitymedical.com/wordpress/)) How can I solve this? [Here](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/wp-content/plugins/nivo-slider-pro/scripts/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js?ver=3.2.1) is the entire un-mified js file.

ETA: Just learned, the fade still goes *during* the transition from one slide to the next, and on the first slide before any transition. It would appear the transition effect breaks the fadein of the dir nav.

Comment: anyone care to help? Still an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution:

Ignore the nivo-slider code and right your own script.

Like so....

```
<script>
    $(function(){   
    $('#slider').hover(function(){
        $(".nivo-directionNav a").fadeIn('slow');
      });
    });
</script>
```

I couldn't get the mouse out function to work but it wasn't necssary for my purposes. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

There is a line of code in the un-minified JS that reads

`slider.hover(function(){$('.nivo-directionNav',slider).show();`

Try changing the show there to .fadeIn('fast') as well.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I'm an idiot. I first read your post as that you were adding that block of code on your own, instead of that *being* the code within the js file.

Comment: yeah, this is driving me crazy! Can't find out what's breaking the fade.